# jQuery getJSON print array where name is string

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, json

I have some good practice with using php and mysql, and am now starting with JSON.

I've made a simple json index containing paths to folders, and items inside them:

```
{ "foldery" : [
    {
      "foName": "website/img/bg",
      "files" : [
        "website/img/bg/bg1.jpeg",
        "website/img/bg/bg2.jpg",
        "website/img/bg/bg3.jpg",
        "website/img/bg/bg4.jpeg"
      ]
    },
    {
      "foName": "website/img/post1",
      "files" : [
        "website/img/post1/a.jpeg",
        "website/img/post1/b.jpg",
        "website/img/post1/c.jpeg",
        "website/img/post1/d.jpg"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now here is my jquery, for now returning a big mess of data, somewhere including the info about the contents inside:

```
  $.getJSON("nameindex.json", function(data) {
      console.log(data);
  });
```

What I would like it to do, in mySql looks like this:

```
SELECT files FROM foldery WHERE foName = "website/img/post1"
```

Thus the result, would be an array containing all the files inside post1.

Unfortunately tho, after 2 hours of attempts I have nothing more than the simple console.log code.
Any help would be gladly appreciated

Comment: Do you have a create script from your SQL database? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over your array and check `forName` to equality

```
function select(o, foName) {
    var length = o.foldery.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if (o.foldery[i].foName == foName) {
            return o.foldery[i].files;
        }
    }
}

var result = select(o, "website/img/post1")
console.log(result);
```

Result

```
[ 'website/img/post1/a.jpeg',
  'website/img/post1/b.jpg',
  'website/img/post1/c.jpeg',
  'website/img/post1/d.jpg' ]
```

Comment: and O here is the data from 
`$.getJSON("nameindex.json", function(O) {... });` ?

Comment: Thank you very much. Works like a charm